# App "Hay Day" doesn't start in Genymotion

Tags: android, emulator

I'm trying to run the app "Hay day" in Genymotion. I used [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013322/1643179) to install the play store. Then, I installed hay day from the play store. I did not make any other changes to the virtual system.

When I tap/click the hay day icon, the screen orientation changes to landscape and changes back right afterwards. Nothing else happens, i.e. the app does not start.

Here's the Logcat output for the app start:

```
    05-28 13:50:16.043: D/OpenGLRenderer(528): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8a7fe18): name, size, mSize = 71, 92736, 1426780
    05-28 13:50:16.059: I/ActivityManager(309): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 pkg=com.supercell.hayday cmp=com.supercell.hayday/.GameApp bnds=[120,369][240,519] u=0} from pid 528
    05-28 13:50:16.063: W/audio_hw_primary(116): out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
    05-28 13:50:16.099: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
    05-28 13:50:16.099: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 16384 
    05-28 13:50:16.103: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 337904 bytes, got 13304 
    05-28 13:50:16.103: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 324600 bytes, got 49152 
    05-28 13:50:16.103: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 275448 bytes, got 16384 
    05-28 13:50:16.107: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 259064 bytes, got 4544 
    05-28 13:50:16.107: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 254520 bytes, got 49152 
    05-28 13:50:16.107: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 205368 bytes, got 16384 
    05-28 13:50:16.107: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 188984 bytes, got 4544 
    05-28 13:50:16.107: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 184440 bytes, got 49152 
    05-28 13:50:16.107: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 135288 bytes, got 16384 
    05-28 13:50:16.107: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 118904 bytes, got 4544 
    05-28 13:50:16.107: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 114360 bytes, got 49152 
    05-28 13:50:16.111: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 65208 bytes, got 16384 
    05-28 13:50:16.111: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 48824 bytes, got 4544 
    05-28 13:50:16.111: E/SocketStream(329): readFully was waiting for 44280 bytes, got 32768 
    05-28 13:50:16.127: I/ActivityManager(309): Start proc com.supercell.hayday for activity com.supercell.hayday/.GameApp: pid=1254 uid=10065 gids={3003, 1015, 1028}
    05-28 13:50:16.135: W/audio_hw_primary(116): out_write() limiting sleep time 59274 to 39909
    05-28 13:50:16.175: I/InputReader(309): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
    05-28 13:50:16.175: I/InputReader(309): Device reconfigured: id=1, name='androVM Virtual Input', surface size is now 480x800, mode is 1
    05-28 13:50:16.175: I/InputReader(309): Device reconfigured: id=2, name='androVM via VirtualBox seamless mouse', surface size is now 480x800, mode is 3
    05-28 13:50:16.187: E/SurfaceFlinger(329): setOrientation with orientation=1
    05-28 13:50:16.187: E/SurfaceFlinger(329): setOrientation orientation=1
    05-28 13:50:16.187: E/FramebufferNativeWindow(329): setOrientation with fbDev=0xb8be4af0 fbDev->setOrientation=0xb6006f20 orientation=1
    05-28 13:50:16.187: I/gralloc_vbox86(329): setOrientation: orientation=1
    05-28 13:50:16.187: I/ActivityManager(309): Config changed: {1.0 0mcc0mnc en_US sw320dp w491dp h294dp nrml land finger qwerty/v/v dpad/v s.7}
    05-28 13:50:16.299: E/Trace(1254): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    05-28 13:50:16.327: W/EGL_emulation(403): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    05-28 13:50:16.371: D/dalvikvm(1254): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.supercell.hayday/lib/libg.so 0xa6a12fd0
    05-28 13:50:16.387: A/libc(1254): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x995bfa84 (code=2), thread 1254 (upercell.hayday)
    05-28 13:50:16.491: I/DEBUG(111): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    05-28 13:50:16.491: I/DEBUG(111): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:4.1.1/JRO03S/eng.buildbot.20140326.210658:userdebug/test-keys'
    05-28 13:50:16.491: I/DEBUG(111): pid: 1254, tid: 1254, name: upercell.hayday  >>> com.supercell.hayday <<<
    05-28 13:50:16.491: I/DEBUG(111): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 995bfa84
    05-28 13:50:16.583: I/DEBUG(111):     eax 00000000  ebx 00000014  ecx bfa38914  edx 998164f0
    05-28 13:50:16.583: I/DEBUG(111):     esi 00000000  edi 998164e0
    05-28 13:50:16.583: I/DEBUG(111):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
    05-28 13:50:16.583: I/DEBUG(111):     eip 995bfa84  ebp bfa39118  esp bfa388b8  flags 00010246
    05-28 13:50:16.583: I/DEBUG(111): backtrace:
    05-28 13:50:16.583: I/DEBUG(111):     #00  pc 0011ea84  /system/lib/libhoudini.so (strncpy+2020)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #01  pc 000e6ce9  /system/lib/libhoudini.so (dvm2hdInit+57)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #02  pc 000c5d17  /system/lib/libdvm.so (houdini::hookDlopen(char const*, int, bool*)+311)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #03  pc 0006c2ef  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmLoadNativeCode(char const*, Object*, char**)+655)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #04  pc 0009fd49  /system/lib/libdvm.so (Dalvik_java_lang_Runtime_nativeLoad(unsigned int const*, JValue*)+73)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #05  pc 000c6008  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #06  pc 00029406  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+70)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #07  pc 000265d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+160)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #08  pc 0009111a  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+938)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #09  pc 000a20fa  /system/lib/libdvm.so (Dalvik_java_lang_reflect_Method_invokeNative(unsigned int const*, JValue*)+282)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #10  pc 000c6008  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #11  pc 00029406  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+70)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #12  pc 000265d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+160)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #13  pc 00091779  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, char*)+601)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #14  pc 0006276a  /system/lib/libdvm.so (CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+106)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #15  pc 0005439a  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+42)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #16  pc 00055609  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+969)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #17  pc 000011f7  /system/bin/app_process (main+599)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):     #18  pc 0001722f  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+95)
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111): stack:
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa38878  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3887c  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa38880  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa38884  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa38888  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3888c  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa38890  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa38894  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa38898  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3889c  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388a0  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.587: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388a4  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388a8  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388ac  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388b0  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388b4  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):     #00  bfa388b8  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388bc  bfa38904  [stack]
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388c0  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388c4  bfa38904  [stack]
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388c8  998164e0  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388cc  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388d0  9955f34f  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388d4  998164e0  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388d8  bfa38904  [stack]
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388dc  00000040  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388e0  bfa38904  [stack]
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388e4  996cf860  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388e8  bfa3912c  [stack]
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388ec  b751e53b  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+923)
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388f0  b758c658  /system/lib/libc.so
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa388f4  b8a2d460  [heap]
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          ........  ........
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):     #01  bfa39120  996cf860  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39124  996a1160  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39128  996ad248  /system/lib/libhoudini.so
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3912c  000001fa  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39130  a02e7b34  
    05-28 13:50:16.591: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39134  9f1a9dda  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39138  9dcabd60  /system/lib/libjavacore.so (Posix_access(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jstring*, int))
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3913c  b67bac98  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39140  b8a2d4b0  [heap]
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39144  b8a2d4b0  [heap]
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39148  bfa391f8  [stack]
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3914c  b6781d17  /system/lib/libdvm.so (houdini::hookDlopen(char const*, int, bool*)+311)
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):     #02  bfa39150  bfa391d8  [stack]
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39154  b679a0a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39158  00000003  
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3915c  a6252770  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39160  a6a00000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39164  a6a4df18  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39168  bfa3917c  [stack]
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3916c  b77242c8  
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39170  a6a4def8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39174  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.595: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39178  00000018  
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3917c  00006e6f  
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39180  a6a4dda8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39184  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa39188  00000000  
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):          bfa3918c  00000001  
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):          ........  ........
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111): memory map around fault addr 995bfa84:
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):     994a0000-994a1000 /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):     994a1000-996d7000 /system/lib/libhoudini.so
    05-28 13:50:16.599: I/DEBUG(111):     996d7000-996f3000 /system/lib/libhoudini.so
    05-28 13:50:16.655: I/BootReceiver(309): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_08 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
    05-28 13:50:16.671: D/Zygote(146): Process 1254 terminated by signal (4)
```

I've found out that according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2/17556321#comment34704999_11446049), the error `error opening trace file: No such file or directory` is not the problem. I also googled around to understand the other error and warning lines, but didn't find any helpful information to solve my problem.

I tried several android devices with android version 4.1 to 4.3. None of them worked. The 4.3. devices repeatedly show the message "unfortunately google play services has stopped" while the other devices don't.

I also tried two other Apps, "Clash of Clans" (from the same developer) and "Farm Town: Cookie Day" (from another developer). They're both failing in the same way and with similar log entries, except that for Farm Town there's no `Trying to load lib` line. All 3 apps have their own custom gui and don't seem to use Android Gui Elements. A fourth app, "Quizduell", who's interface is made of android gui elements, works fine.

I also tried the "Android Emulator", and Hay Day works there (using the same computer).

I'm using Win7 32bit, Genymotion 2.2.0 and VirtualBox 4.3.10.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem in Genymotion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ARM support (see the 'houdini' in the trace). You may want to look around and find out how to add this, since genymotion removed this from their release. There are packages / flashable archive available which you can install to get this working.

For example:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/oe6slq3Da5c